# Is it possible to push to another view controller and then access a method from within that view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

Is it possible to push (from a UIButton) to another view controller and then access a method from within that view controller?

my code below pushes the RootViewController on the stack. There's a method within the RootViewController that I'd like to run. Can I do it from the following code somehow?

```
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc]         
                                           initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" 
                                           bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any method that is visible in the RootViewController header can be accessed like you would call any method on any other object. For instance `[rootViewController someMethod]`.

If you call it directly after the pushViewController, the method will run before the view controller actually animates onto the screen on the next iteration of the runloop.

Though it's probably best that you do whatever it is you are wanting to do in the `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:`, or `viewDidAppear:` methods of your RootViewController, unless it's something you don't usually want to happen.

Comment: thanks! how would this code look like if I added [rootViewController someMethod] to it? It's the syntax I'm having trouble with. RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Just add `[rootViewController someMethod];` after the last line where you push the view controller and it will run. The statements run in order.

Comment: it works! thanks again. I had to declare the method in the .h file and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can just access the function with something like:

```
[rootViewController functionName];
```